# input radio don't work on ios touch devices (vue js app)

Tags: ios, iphone, css, input, vuejs2

i am developing a web app who have custom input radio checkboxes that are not selectable using ios devices (ipad and iphone), i have alredy put the onclick="" event on labels but still nothing, does anybody have the idea how to solve this problem?

here the demo url:
http://www.mixink.it/ascom/altopiemonte/

HTML

```
                        <input 
                    type="radio"
                    v-bind:id="['gialla-'+index]"
                    name="serviziGialla" 
                    v-bind:value="servizio.nomeServizio"
                    v-model="giallaPicked"
                    v-on:click="AddServizi(servizio.selected,servizio.classe,servizio.nomeServizio,servizio.descrizione,servizio.descrizione_lunga,index,servizio.x,servizio.y)"/>
                    <label onclick=""
                    v-bind:for="['gialla-'+index]"
                    ><span></span>
                    </label>
```

CSS

```
label span {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#ylwLine input[type="radio"] + label span {
    background:url(../img/yellow-off.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#ylwLine input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background:url(../img/yellow-on.svg) !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. Try to get rid of all the "cursor: move" in parents or add handlers in code js

```
$("#ylwLine label").onclick = function () {};
```

Comment: seems that if i use interact.js with input radio inside it, the radio button don't work.. good but not that good

Comment: Yes, I checked it, it works now, but dragging doesn't work. Apparently some event, interrupts handlers (input check) on ios.